# Getting records using DataMapper

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Just using DataMapper for the first time. I have set up a table in a MySQL database and am connecting to that. I have defined the following mapping:

```
class Track_Scan
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :item_id,                  Integer
    property :current_station_id,       Integer
    property :next_station_id,          Integer
end
```

It returns the right *number* of items - e.g. if there are five records in the DB for a given id, `Track_Scan.all(:item_id => my_id)` will yield a group of five objects - but when I call each on this, I see the same object five times:

```
#<Track_Scan:0x7fcbcfca59c0>
#<Track_Scan:0x7fcbcfca59c0>
#<Track_Scan:0x7fcbcfca59c0>
#<Track_Scan:0x7fcbcfca59c0>
#<Track_Scan:0x7fcbcfca59c0>
```

rather than five different objects with different values in their `current_station_id` and `next_station_id` as they actually do in the table.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model is missing a key. If you want to use a composite key you need to do this:

```
class Track_Scan
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :item_id,            Integer, :key => true
  property :current_station_id, Integer, :key => true
  property :next_station_id,    Integer, :key => true
end
```

Also, after all your models are required you need to call:

```
DataMapper.finalize
```

Hope this helps